# slideDown, slideUp not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

Hi Friends slideDown and slideUp function are not working with my code. It appears the hidden row without slideDown effect PLease help guys you can chekc my code below or **[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JNKaR/)**

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><p>Logistics</p>
      <select name=" " >
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>three</option>
        <option>four</option>
        <option>Others</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="80%" colspan="2"><textarea name=" 5" rows="2" id=" 5" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = ''">Others Details</textarea>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('tr').has('textarea').hide();
$('select').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()=='Others')
    {
        //$(this).next('tr td').has('textarea').slideDown(200);
        $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').next('tr').slideDown(200);
        //alert('other')
        }
    else
    {
        //$(this).next('tr td').has('textarea').slideDown(200);
        $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').next('tr').slideUp(200);
        //alert('other')
        }
    })
```

Comment: see http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JNKaR/3/)**</kbd>

#### JQuery

```
$('tr').not(':first').children('td').wrapInner('<div>');
$('select').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()=='Others')
    {
        $('td > div').slideDown(2000, function() {
            $(this).parent().slideDown(2000);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('td > div').slideUp(1000, function() {
            $(this).parent().slideUp();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not slide table rows, as you can't manipulate the height of them. jQuery's animation relies upon the element having height and width.

Inline elements do not have these dimensions set or settable, so animations must make them block-level elements.It's probably better to just use regular, non-animated, `hide` and `show` for such elements.

You can also use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JNKaR/2/)**

Comment: the problem is not that it is not appearing... the sliding effect is not there... see http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2041

Comment: @ArunPJohny:OP also has incorrect logic. textarea was not appearing. and that bug is not fixable. user may have to use animate instead.

Comment: it is appearing if others is selected